# Method findText with regexp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to find a string in the google document using findText(searchPattern) method. My searchPattern is regexp as in following:

```
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  var textToHighlight = '';
  textToHighlight = new RegExp(  "this" ); 
  textLocation = doc.findText(textToHighlight);
```

But it gave me the following error instead search the text:

> Google Apps Script: Argument cannot be null: prompt

I read the documentation of the findText method in Text class. Here it specifies the searchPattern as string. Is there any alternative to find the text using regexp.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass a string to this function, but it will convert it into RegExp for you. This is **not** like the `string.match` function that differentiates strings from regexes.

`doc.findText("any\\s+regex.*works");`